# Pulling from a remote branch to a local branch

Tags: git, github

I am working on a local branch, and a team member has made made some changes to that branch.  How do I "pull/fetch" their changes, to my local branch?

I do not want to pull the entire repo, just this branch.

Comment: how the team member could made that change if its a local branch?

Comment: I had previously pushed the local to the remote, so they had access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before this checkout the branch what your colleagues use

```
git checkout [branch]
```

If all of you use master branch, skip this step.

And pull only one branch (and merge vith your local branch) Use this:

```
git pull [repo] [branch]
```

For example:

```
git pull origin master
```

If you want only download the changes and after want to merge:

```
git fetch [repo] [branch]
git merge [repo]/[branch]
```

for example:

```
git fetch origin master
git merge origin/master #the local copy of the master branch in origin repo
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something as simple as that, Thanks.

Comment: yes git has a clean logic, but that is some time to experience all of the features. you welcome :)